# Javassist, java

Tags: java, javassist

I'm doing a task to create a java-application. The task is to change the method (calculation formula) without recompiling the application. After searching in Google, I realized that you can solve the problem with the help of javassist. So far I'm trying on a simple example. 
So, the class containing the only method I want to change

```
package ru.testScandJavaCafee.service;
public class Helper {
public String createList()
{
    System.out.println("++++");
    return "1000";
}
}
```

And the class from which I change the method

```
package ru.testScandJavaCafee.controller;

import javassist.*;
import ru.testScandJavaCafee.service.Helper;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;


/**
 * Created by 15 on 06.05.2017.
 */

public class CoffeeTypeController {

public String createMethodHelper() throws NotFoundException, CannotCompileException, NoSuchMethodException, InvocationTargetException, IllegalAccessException, IOException, InstantiationException, ClassNotFoundException {

    ClassPool pool = ClassPool.getDefault();
    ClassPool.getDefault().insertClassPath(new ClassClassPath(ru.testScandJavaCafee.service.Helper2.class));

    CtClass cc = pool.get("ru.testScandJavaCafee.service.Helper");

    CtMethod cm = cc.getMethod("createList","()Ljava/lang/String;" );

    cm.setBody( "{  return \"200 \" ;}" );
    cc.toClass();

    Helper helper = new Helper();
    Method method1 = helper.getClass().getMethod("createList");
    String sum = (String)method1.invoke(helper);
    return sum;
}
```

After starting I get the output

```
javassist.CannotCompileException: by java.lang.LinkageError: loader (instance of  org/apache/catalina/loader/WebappClassLoader): attempted  duplicate class definition for name: "ru/testScandJavaCafee/service/Helper2"
    at javassist.ClassPool.toClass(ClassPool.java:1085)
    at javassist.ClassPool.toClass(ClassPool.java:1028)
    at javassist.ClassPool.toClass(ClassPool.java:986)
    at javassist.CtClass.toClass(CtClass.java:1110)
    at ru.testScandJavaCafee.controller.CoffeeTypeController.createMethodHelper(CoffeeTypeController.java:111)
    at ru.testScandJavaCafee.controller.CoffeeTypeController.doPost(CoffeeTypeController.java:56)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:218)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:110)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:506)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:962)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:452)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1087)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:318)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.LinkageError: loader (instance of  org/apache/catalina/loader/WebappClassLoader): attempted  duplicate class definition for name: "ru/testScandJavaCafee/service/Helper2"
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:642)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at javassist.ClassPool.toClass2(ClassPool.java:1098)
    at javassist.ClassPool.toClass(ClassPool.java:1079)
    ... 27 more
```

help to understand how to fix the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You error is in this line:

```
ClassPool.getDefault().insertClassPath(new ClassClassPath(ru.testScandJavaCafee.service.Helper2.class));
```

First, you already created the pool so should insert the classpath to that pool. Second, the class path is supposed to be the class name of the class where your code resides.

```
pool.insertClassPath(new ClassClassPath(this.getClass()));
```

Check out the [documentation](http://jboss-javassist.github.io/javassist/tutorial/tutorial.html#read). The section on `Class search path`

Comment: Thank you so much! But now there is a second problem - when you re-query the error ru.testScandJavaCafee.service.Helper class is frozen, and if I add cc.defrost (), it gives an error  javassist.CannotCompileException: by java.lang.LinkageError: loader (instance of  org/apache/catalina/loader/WebappClassLoader): attempted  duplicate class definition for name: "ru/testScandJavaCafee/service/Helper"
 at javassist.ClassPool.toClass(ClassPool.java:1085)
 at javassist.ClassPool.toClass(ClassPool.java:1028)
 at javassist.ClassPool.toClass(ClassPool.java:986)

Comment: i'm not sure, but it maybe because the method tries to initialize everything again in the same run. From what I understand the `defrost()` method allows you to make additional changes, but to the same instances.

Answer (score 2):

Use
`cc.getClass();`

Instead of:
`cc.toClass();`

From my experience, the line below looks like it's causing the problem:

```
cm.setBody( "{  return \"200 \" ;}" );
cc.toClass(); <<<<<<<<<<<<< // duplicate class definition here.
```

The .toClass essentially tries to convert to a class but it already exists which is why you're getting duplicate class definition.

[CtClass](http://www.javassist.org/html/javassist/CtClass.html) Look for ".toClass()"

Also I don't see why you've done that since you don't use `cc` beyond that line.